# Handling nested if/else statements using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a condition where there are some checks to be made in order to create an object. 
I am using `Stream`s for this, and I'm having a tough time in getting this done.

The input is a `HashMap` object with key/value pairs and output should be below.

```
| userrole   | userid | username | output   |
|------------|--------|----------|----------|
| "" (blank) | 111    | amathews | 111      |
| ""         |        | amathews | amathews |
| Admin      | 111    | amathews | 111      |
| Admin      | 111    | ""       | 111      |
| Admin      |        | amathews | Admin    |
```

This is how the precedence is: userid>userrole>username.

Each `HashMap` object will contain userrole/username/userid as key and its values along with other key/value pairs.
We will have a bunch of nested if/else statements to accomplish this task in prior versions of Java.

Here is my code:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() instanceof String || e.getValue() instanceof Integer)
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("userrole") || e.getKey().contains("userid") || e.getKey().contains("username") )
        .map(e -> e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I know that the way I have written map function in the `Stream` is not correct too.
How to accomplish this in java 8? I do not know how to add the nested if/else part here.

Edit : Sorry If I hadn't stated the problem precisely. Here is the code snippet:

```
public List<UserAction> getUserActionList(Map<String, String> map)
    {
        String userRole = map.get("userrole");
        String userName = map.get("username");
        String userId = map.get("userid");

        String output = null;
        // if userrole, userid and username are not null/empty, then output is userid 
        if(!checkForNullEmpty(userRole) && !checkForNullEmpty(userId) && !checkForNullEmpty(userName))
            output = userId;
        // if userrole and userid are null/empty and username is not empty/null, then output is username
        else if(checkForNullEmpty(userRole) && checkForNullEmpty(userId) && !checkForNullEmpty(userName))
            output = userName;
        // if userid and username are null/empty and userrole is not empty/null, then output is userrole
        else if(!checkForNullEmpty(userRole) && checkForNullEmpty(userId) && checkForNullEmpty(userName))
            output = userRole;

        List<UserAction> udList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Add the map and output into a UserAction object
        udList.add(new UserAction(map, output));

        return udList;

    }
```

I had handled only 3 conditions here as per the table. So this has to refactored to use java 8 `Stream`s. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: What's your actual problem? Does the code you have posted not work? If not, why not? If it does work, what are you asking exactly? Maybe post some executable code that has sample data and what the desired data type should be

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the snippet hope its clear now.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that at least one of the values will be found in the map?

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. Yes it is guaranteed to  contain at least one of the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If at least one of the values is guaranteed, you could refactor it like this:

```
public List<UserAction> getUserActionList(Map<String, String> map) {
    return Stream.of("userid", "username", "userrole")
        .map(map::get)
        .filter(s -> !checkForNullEmpty(s))
        .limit(1)
        .map(output -> new UserAction(map, output))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If it is *not* guaranteed that at least one value will be non-null, it's a little uglier, but not too bad:

```
public List<UserAction> getUserActionList(Map<String, String> map) {
    return Stream.of("userid", "username", "userrole")
        .map(map::get)
        .filter(s -> !checkForNullEmpty(s))
        .limit(1)
        .map(output -> new UserAction(map, output))
        .map(Collections::singletonList)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(() -> Arrays.asList(new UserAction(map, null)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this @bohemian. I am just trying to understand how this works. So first of all we are trying to create a stream of required keys, then we will get the values for this from the map object, filter off the null/blank ones, then limit one to get one of the value, create a UserAction object and at last collect all the objects into a list.. what I didn't understand is how it will prioritise I.e. userid>userrole>username?? Meaning as per the table I've with the conditions, As depicted in my code snippet. So this will become nested if/else right...

Comment: @15R6 you've basically got it, but notice `.limit(1)`. This means the stream stops after the first element collected. Any items in the stream after the first hit aren't even pulled through. For example, if `map.get"userid")` returns a value, ’map.get()` is not called again. Streams fire all the way through one element at a time. They don't proceed through the steps with all elements before going to the next step. Hope this has helped.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear about the task you need to accomplish, but in general, everything that you need to write in your `if` statements you can do with `filter()` method from `Stream API`. Then, in `map()` method you'd have the exact logic which is needed to be done with the data (e.g. transforming it to some other type or getting values which are needed). `collect()` method is used to create a result from the `Stream`, e.g. list, set, map, single object or anything else. For example:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> {
                    // filter the data here, so if isStrOrInt or containsUserData is false - we will not have it in map() method
                    boolean isStrOrInt = e.getValue() instanceof String || e.getValue() instanceof Integer;
                    boolean containsUserData = e.getKey().contains("userrole") || e.getKey().contains("userid") || e.getKey().contains("username");
                    return isStrOrInt && containsUserData;
                })
                .map(e -> {
                    if (e.getKey().contains("userrole")) {
                        // do something
                    }
                    // some more logic here
                    return e.getValue();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                // or e.g. .reduce((value1, value2) -> value1 + value2);
```

If you need to create a single object in the end, you would probably need `reduce()` method. I recommend you to check [reduction operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html), general information about [Stream API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) to understand how they work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @yuriy. Yes I understood what you have answered. I will try this way too. Any other suggestion after seeing the edited question with the code snippet?